# How to count row's in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

this is my table:

```
ID/Number/Date
1/111/2021-01-01
2/111/2021-01-02
6/333/2921-01-01
```

I need a table which count the rows based on Number order by Date asc.
This should be my final table:

```
ID/Number/Date/Row_No_Count
1/111/2021-01-01/1
2/111/2021-01-02/2
6/333/2921-01-01/1
```

How to achieve this with hive? Is their any function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Row Number is a Function IN SQL Server for this type of Work.**
You can solve Your Problem on based on below Query .

Query : `Select *,row_number () Over (partition by Number order by Number) 'Row_Number_Count' From t ;`
Output :

```
 id          Number      Date       Row_Number_Count
----------- ----------- ---------- --------------------
1           111         2021-01-01    1
2           111         2021-01-02    2
6           333         2921-01-01    1
```

(3 rows affected)

Answer (score 0):

try row_number() window function like below.

```
select t.*,
row_number() over(partition by Number  order by  Number,Date asc ) as Row_No_Count
from table t
```

Comment: (Minor comment) Why do you specify `asc` for Date, but not for ID or Number?

Comment: By default everything are ordered by `asc`. So, if you dont need to sort anything in desc specifically, you dont have to mention. For date, i mentioned just to clarify but i dont have to/need to. Also, this window order is not display order, so this wont add any value i think.